# Incorrect bounding box recovered for an Axes created via AxesDivider.append_axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Using matplotlib (version 3.5.0), I am trying to get the bounding box of an `Axes` instance that I have created using the `AxesDivider.append_axes` method. Namely, this new axis is created to hold the colorbar for the main axis image. Thus, I have the code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)

im1 = ax1.imshow([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
ax1_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
# Add an Axes to the right of the main Axes.
cax1 = ax1_divider.append_axes("right", size="10%", pad="0%")
cb1 = fig.colorbar(im1, cax=cax1)

plt.show()
```

This creates the following figure showing both the main axis and its colorbar:

[image]

Now I wish to locate the bounding box of the colorbar axis in display coordinates (or even figure fraction, I'm easy!), so I use the `Axes.get_position` method i.e.:

```py
print(ax1.get_position())
print(cax1.get_position())
```

Which yields the following output:

```
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.125, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.125, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
```

As you can see, counter-intuitively the bounding box of the colorbar's axis (`cax1`) is apparently the exact same as the main axis' (`ax1`) bounding box.

My question is, how do I recover the actual bounding box of the colorbar axis (`cax1`)?

I was expecting a correct bounding box for `cax1` of (roughly, if I calculated by hand correctly):

```
Bbox(x0=0.8225, y0=0.125, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
```

**UPDATE**: After Yannick Copin's answer below, I reran everything... It appears that the results of `cax.get_position()` depend upon when they are called in relation to `plt.show()`. Before results in:

```
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
```

Whereas, placing the `cax1.get_position()` call after `plt.show()` results in the 'correct' bounding boxes:

```
Bbox(x0=0.19487500000000002, y0=0.11000000000000004, x1=0.7723749999999999, y1=0.8799999999999999)
Bbox(x0=0.7723749999999999, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.830125, y1=0.88)
```

My temporary fix is to call `fig.canvas.draw()` just before the point at which I need accurate `Axes` dimensions via `cax1.get_position()`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of matplotlib are you using? On my side (`matplotlib.__version__` = 3.7.1), the `Bbox`es returns seem correct (and with another output format than yours):

```py
In [3]: ax1.get_position()
Out[3]: Bbox([[0.19487500000000002, 0.11000000000000004], [0.7723749999999999, 0.8799999999999999]])

In [4]: cax1.get_position()
Out[4]: Bbox([[0.7723749999999999, 0.10999999999999999], [0.830125, 0.88]])
```

Comment: I'm using matplotlib version 3.5.0 (I've updated my question with this info)